# Programmatically collapse all react-accessible accordion panels

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I'm using a [react-accessible-accordion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-accessible-accordion) to present the user with a form one panel at a time. There is a "Reset" button that resets the impacts of any of the buttons the user may have pushed. The buttons are inside the panels. How do you programmatically collapse any open panels? There is the dangerouslySetExpanded option for an AccordionItem, but I don't see any practical examples of this being used or thorough documentation of the option (this is where that [option is described in the docs](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion#dangerouslysetexpanding-boolean-optional)). Do I have to use state variables here for the expanded-collapsed state of each item to be able to manipulate it programmatically? Here's a simplified version of the code I have now:

```
import React from 'react';
import ToggleButton from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButton";
import ButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Accordion, AccordionItem, AccordionItemHeading, AccordionItemButton, AccordionItemPanel} from 'react-accessible-accordion';


export const AccordionComponent = props => {
  stateHooks = [React.useState(-1), React.useState(-1)]
  const [ [varA, setVarA], [varB, setVarB] ] = stateHooks
  
  const handleResetAccordion = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    stateHooks.forEach(hook => {  // pass -1 to each setter
      hook[1]('-1');  // index 1 contains the setter
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="accordion_container">
      <Accordion allowZeroExpanded={true}>
        <AccordionItem>
          <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton> Panel #1 Title </AccordionItemButton>
          </AccordionItemHeading>
          <AccordionItemPanel>
            <div className='radioQuestionCard'>
              <h3>Question #1 Prompt:</h3>
              <ButtonGroup className='radio' toggle id='q1'>
                <ToggleButton key='0' type="radio" name="q1" value='0' checked={varA === '0'}
                  onChange={e => setVarA(e.currentTarget.value)} > Q1: Option1
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton key='1' type="radio" name="q1" value='1' checked={varA === '1'}
                  onChange={e => setVarA(e.currentTarget.value)} > Q1: Option2
                </ToggleButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
          </AccordionItemPanel>
        </AccordionItem>
        <AccordionItem>
          <AccordionItemHeading>
            <AccordionItemButton> Panel #2 Title </AccordionItemButton>
          </AccordionItemHeading>
          <AccordionItemPanel>
            <div className='radioQuestionCard'>
              <h3>Question #2 Prompt:</h3>
              <ButtonGroup className='radio' toggle id='q2'>
                <ToggleButton key='0' type="radio" name="q2" value='0' checked={varB === '0'}
                  onChange={e => setVarB(e.currentTarget.value)} > Q2: Option1
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton key='1' type="radio" name="q2" value='1' checked={varB === '1'}
                  onChange={e => setVarB(e.currentTarget.value)} > Q2: Option2
                </ToggleButton>
              </ButtonGroup>
            </div>
          </AccordionItemPanel>
        </AccordionItem>
      </Accordion>
      <button className='btn btn-danger btn-sm'
        onClick={handleResetAccordion} id='resetAccordion'> Reset
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're already doing it with the reset function.  What do you mean by "programmatically collapse any open panels"?  When do you want to collapse them all?

Comment: The use case is that someone is making selections using the buttons in the panel, and then realizes that they want to reset all their answers. That much is done by the handleResetAccordion method, but I want the open panels to be closed too. This currently leaves open panels open.

Comment: Did you try adding a `dangerouslySetExpanded` prop on the `AccordianItem`s?  A couple other things - the docs say `dangerouslySetExpanding`, but that's wrong.  And above, you are checking for varA in item b, may just be a pseudo-code typo.  Looking at the code here - https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/tree/master/src/components - you can see how the prop is used.

Comment: Bottom example here - https://react-accessible-accordion.springload.co.nz/

Comment: @MarkSwardstrom I linked to that example in my original question, but it is manual assignment, not programmatic. In other words, you can force certain panels to be open from the start, but this is not dynamic and the accordion can no longer be manipulated by the user. The dangerouslySetExpanded flag has an extremely narrow use case.

Answer (score 5):

The react-accessible-accordion intentionally omits the ability to programmatically control the expanded state of the accordion panels, so a work-around I found is to put the whole accordion inside of a div, and give that div a key parameter. When the key changes, the accordion will be forcibly reinitialized.

```
let accordion_key = 12345;

const handleReinitialize = () => accordion_key++;

return(
  <div className="accordion_container" key={accordion_key}>
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionItem>
        <AccordionItemHeading>
        ... etc.
    <button onClick={handleReinitialize} id='reinitialize'>Reinitialize Accordion</button>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: When I re-init I lose my current state when using this for FORM tech. In other words, be careful of your use case when using this method otherwise {children} contained within the AccordionItem will re-init...

Comment: This method works, but there is no need to wrap accordion inside a div. The kay can be set for the accordion directly.

Comment: In this case the div is necessary because React requires you to return a single element so you can't have the Accordion and the button as two loose elements. But you're right that the key can just go directly on the Accordion instead.

Comment: You can use `<React.Fragment>` if you want to avoid an extra div

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just make it a boolean variable and change it programmatically.  If its value is undefined, it will use the button state value.

```
<AccordionItem dangerouslySetExpanded={isExpanded}> 
...
</AccordionItem>
```

where `isExpanded` is set by a setState variable somewhere

```
const [ isExpanded, setIsExpanded ] = setState()
```

```
const closeAll = () => {
  setIsExpanded(false)
}
```

Comment: This does close all of the AccordionItems, but they can no longer be interacted with by the user, so the user can't open them again if false. If set to false, and then undefined, the button state will reopen whatever was closed.

Answer (score 0):

For the older version you can try using the expanded prop of react accessible dropdown and then add and an onclick to a div element in the AccordionItemTitle.

```
<AccordionItem uuid="a" expanded={()=>this.setIsCollapse("a")}>
<AccordionItemTitle> 
 <div onClick={(value)=>this.onChangeAccordion(value)}>
 </div>   
</AccordionItemTitle>  
</AccordionItem>
```